# The Stack Overflow API doesn't return the owner on some answers

Tags: discussion, api, stack-overflow

I work with the Stack Overflow API and found something strange. Following are the steps to reproduce:

- Open http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/similar?answers=true&body=true&comments=true&title=stored%20queries
- Find '461351'
- The answer with '461351' answer_id has no owner.

Is this a bug or normal behavior whose condition to occur I don't know?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this belongs on meta, as it's a programming problem involving an API that happens to be hosted on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That's because that answer doesn't have an owner anymore:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460300/storing-queries-in-c-sharp-or-use-stored-functions-in-postgres/461351#461351)

[image: Showing the answer with grayed out author information]

This can have the following reasons:

- The account was deleted for some reason.
- The answer was disassociated from the account for some reason.
- The question was migrated from another site and the user doesn't have an account on the target site *(obviously not in this case)*.

Comment: Does this not break the Attribution part of the license?

Comment: @Rawling: Interesting question. Maybe you want to ask that as separate question, because this raises very interesting thoughts.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.